# How to replace dummy values with missing in Julia Dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a set of weather data from ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/.

The dataset includes temperatures and rainfall etc. and uses -9999 as a dummy value to represent missing data.

I would like to replace that value with `missing` in a DataFrame so that it will not be included in statistical calculations or plots. Is there a way I can do this as I create the dataframe? Or can it be done after the dataframe is created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additionally to what Dan Getz proposes there are two options:

#### use `recode` function

(the `recode` function is defined in the CategoricalArrays.jl package so you need to load it first)

I am using Dan's example:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=rand(10),y=[rand()<0.3 ? 9999.0 : rand() for i=1:10])
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x         │ y        │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.856388  │ 0.322763 │
│ 2   │ 0.360254  │ 9999.0   │
│ 3   │ 0.229875  │ 0.906697 │
│ 4   │ 0.275965  │ 0.485042 │
│ 5   │ 0.126336  │ 0.205509 │
│ 6   │ 0.879974  │ 0.752962 │
│ 7   │ 0.0518579 │ 9999.0   │
│ 8   │ 0.512231  │ 0.759513 │
│ 9   │ 0.309586  │ 9999.0   │
│ 10  │ 0.616471  │ 0.978771 │

julia> df[:y] = recode(df[:y], 9999.0=>missing)
10-element Array{Union{Float64, Missings.Missing},1}:
 0.322763
  missing
 0.906697
 0.485042
 0.205509
 0.752962
  missing
 0.759513
  missing
 0.978771

julia> df
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x         │ y        │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.856388  │ 0.322763 │
│ 2   │ 0.360254  │ missing  │
│ 3   │ 0.229875  │ 0.906697 │
│ 4   │ 0.275965  │ 0.485042 │
│ 5   │ 0.126336  │ 0.205509 │
│ 6   │ 0.879974  │ 0.752962 │
│ 7   │ 0.0518579 │ missing  │
│ 8   │ 0.512231  │ 0.759513 │
│ 9   │ 0.309586  │ missing  │
│ 10  │ 0.616471  │ 0.978771 │
```

Additionally if you want to recode the whole `DataFrame` (all columns) into a new data frame you can use `colwise`:

```
julia> DataFrame(colwise(x -> recode(x, 9999.0=>missing), df), names(df))
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x         │ y        │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.856388  │ 0.322763 │
│ 2   │ 0.360254  │ missing  │
│ 3   │ 0.229875  │ 0.906697 │
│ 4   │ 0.275965  │ 0.485042 │
│ 5   │ 0.126336  │ 0.205509 │
│ 6   │ 0.879974  │ 0.752962 │
│ 7   │ 0.0518579 │ missing  │
│ 8   │ 0.512231  │ 0.759513 │
│ 9   │ 0.309586  │ missing  │
│ 10  │ 0.616471  │ 0.978771 │
```

#### detect `missing`s when creating `DataFrame`

Here it depends on the package you use to load the data. For instance if you use *CSV.jl* you can add `null="-9999"` keyword argument to `CSV.read`. In more complex cases you can use `transforms` keyword argument and e.g. use an adjusted version of `val2missing` proposed by Dan there.

Comment: Bogumił Kamiński
I am using your recent tutorial to learn DataFrames. Thanks for doing that.
The data is in fixed-width-format and apparently there is no function in CSV.jl for that format. Perhaps you could remedy that.
An example datafile is here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4uo7w3d4wjlxs5/USW00023183.dly?dl=0
I wrote a function to load a fwf file into a DataFrame. My function is here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7wmre60q1u0xxn/read_dly.jl?dl=0
I used your colwise/recode suggestion.
Thanks again.
Now, how do I mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: Since you have manually calculated column locations probably there is not much to improve (maybe code cleanup - e.g. to keep column names, widths and parser functions in an array). You could use `scan` function from my package https://github.com/bkamins/FWF.jl to detect columns automatically but you have already done that. There is one caveat: your code will work for ASCII text (and fortunately you have ASCII data), but it would fail on general UTF-8 text, but it is a separate issue (FWF.jl would handle this). To mark answer as accepted you can click on a check mark next to my answer.

Comment: The column widths are given in the readme at ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/  so it is easy to put them into the read_dly.jl code. The UTF-8 text is not an issue with this dataset but I will study FWF.jl to see how to apply it with other data.  Thanks again. Please continue your good work with Julia!

Comment: FWF.jl is WIP right now and only works on Julia 0.7 (there is a redesign of string infrastructure in 0.7 which is backwards incompatible). The crucial issue is UTF-8 to be careful about, because one should use jumps by character index not byte index in such cases - and this is what `nextind` is designed for.

Comment: Very Good. I will have to wait until Julia 0.7 is available in the software repositories for my distro (Fedora) but on second thought, probably the data for my area of interest, weather and climate will be in ascii format anyway.

Comment: FWIW you can find Julia 0.7 RPM nightlies here: https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/nalimilan/julia-nightlies/

Answer (score 0):

The following example defines a function (named `val2missing`) to replace a specified value with `missing` and then applies this function using the `.` broadcast notation. The example first generates a random dataset (to simulate the weather data) with 9999.0 (this data is in `df`). It then creates `df2` with `missing` values from `df`:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Missings

julia> df = DataFrame(x=rand(10),y=[rand()<0.3 ? 9999.0 : rand() for i=1:10])
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y         │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.926893 │ 0.9355    │
│ 2   │ 0.961057 │ 9999.0    │
│ 3   │ 0.308849 │ 9999.0    │
│ 4   │ 0.936876 │ 0.303936  │
│ 5   │ 0.541762 │ 0.5957    │
│ 6   │ 0.953278 │ 9999.0    │
│ 7   │ 0.987931 │ 9999.0    │
│ 8   │ 0.904365 │ 0.0227427 │
│ 9   │ 0.640827 │ 0.960697  │
│ 10  │ 0.66238  │ 0.769464  │

julia> val2missing(v,mv) = mv == v ? missing : v
val2missing (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df2 = DataFrame(x=df[:x], y=val2missing.(df[:y],9999.0))
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x        │ y         │
├─────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.926893 │ 0.9355    │
│ 2   │ 0.961057 │ missing   │
│ 3   │ 0.308849 │ missing   │
│ 4   │ 0.936876 │ 0.303936  │
│ 5   │ 0.541762 │ 0.5957    │
│ 6   │ 0.953278 │ missing   │
│ 7   │ 0.987931 │ missing   │
│ 8   │ 0.904365 │ 0.0227427 │
│ 9   │ 0.640827 │ 0.960697  │
│ 10  │ 0.66238  │ 0.769464  │
```