# Julia recode not defined

Tags: python, dataframe, julia, ijulia-notebook

So I am learning Julia and I am trying to replace missing values with NaN values in my array with the help of recode function, like this :
`recode([1.0, missing, 2.0, missing], missing=>NaN)` 
But I get an error stating this :

```
UndefVarError: recode not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[18]:1
 [2] eval
   @ ./boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:1196
```

I can only find helping [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554416/how-to-replace-dummy-values-with-missing-in-julia-dataframes) for older versions of Julia where the recode works perfectly but not for Julia 1.7.0 
Does anyone know if it is deprecated or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely referring to the [`recode`](https://categoricalarrays.juliadata.org/stable/apiindex/#CategoricalArrays.recode) function that is defined in CategoricalArrays.jl package. Please load this package first:

```
using CategoricalArrays
```

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer tells you were is `recode`, note that you can also just use `coalesce`:

```
julia> coalesce.([1.0, missing, 2.0, missing], NaN)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
   1.0
 NaN
   2.0
 NaN
```